# How to stack two header tags instead of side by side

Tags: html, css, header, tags

The current header tags are side by side and I'm trying to get the second header tag to sit underneath the first.

I currently have h1 and h2 tags. I have tried putting it all into an h1 tag and using span, however, the styling on span does not take well when sizing and aligning. I am trying to have it centered on the screen and have the subtitle directly underneath of the title, centered by the middle, not left aligned and next to it.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("underneath.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 15%;
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.name {
  font-size: 6em;
  display: inline;
}

.subtitle {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="name">Answer 42</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">Customer Acquistions</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

I am trying to create a title for the page with a subtitle underneath of it and have it centered above a background image I put in CSS. My current code has the the header tags side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this simple solution will help you.

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("underneath.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.wrapper {
    padding-top: 15%;
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.name {
    font-size: 6em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.subtitle {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="name">Answer 42</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle">Customer Acquistions</h2>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the entire problem.